# How to copy to clipboard in chrome extension with a link?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have recently created a chrome extension for the first time. I have a copy button on my page which works fine when the extension is loaded as a web page. However, when I load it as an extension the copy function doesn't work.

My `manifest.json` permissions looks like this:

```
"permissions": [
  "webNavigation",
  "storage",
  "clipboardWrite",
  "clipboardRead"
]
```

The code in my `popout.html` page to copy looks like this:

```
        <div id="legacyCopyLabel">
            <a onclick="copyText(getElementById('legacy'))" class="alignright">COPY</a>
        </div>
```

and the `copyText()` function in my javascript code looks like this:

```
function copyText(element) {
    var range, selection, worked;

    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
      range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(element);
      range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();        
      range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(element);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }

    try {
      document.execCommand('copy');
      updateStatus ('Copied address', 'info');
    }
    catch (err) {
      alert('Unable to copy the address');
    }
  }
```

Full code is here if you want to look: https://github.com/markallisongit/handcash-chrome

Chrome extension is on the chrome store here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/handcash-handle-converter/bnkohbkbipagdhplhkhgonbalbjigpoh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you use inline JS: `<a onclick="...">`. 
According to Chrome's Content Security Police:

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline  blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. ).

The solution will be to put your code into a separate `.js` file and include it as a usual JS-script.

Comment: Thanks I created some event handlers in a separate javascript file and now it works fine.